# Substituir acentos e cedilhas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou com um problema em javascript faço um **`window.open()`** com uma string o problema é que se a string tiver acentos ou cedilhas dá erro , alguem sabe um maneira de substituir os acentos ou cedilhas pela letra sem acento ou cedilhas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `encodeURI` para URL-encode os caracteres.

```
var url = 'http://my.url.com/que/tem/ç/cedilha/e/ãé/acentos';
var encoded = encodeURI(url);
window.open(encoded);
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4gxx8fq/).

Comment: Eu tentei mas não esta a a funcionar

Comment: Se encoding os caracteres acentuados não funciona, o que você quer é remover os acentos? Por exemplo, "çaéiôü" => "caeiou"? Se for o caso, pode dar uma olhada [nessa questão do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/990904/751090).